# facebook audience network in appcelerator titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, facebook-audience-network

I want to integrate Facebook audience network in Appcelerator titanium. Has anyone integrated the same in titanium ?
Facebook tutorial is completely in native code and I have no idea how to start with it. 
Please guide me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator doesn't have any plan on supporting Facebook Audience Network. The only way would be using Hyperloop with Cocoapods as shown in this ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19626?focusedCommentId=433515&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-433515

1. Add pod 'FBAudienceNetwork' to your Podfile
2. Import the framework

   `var FBInterstitialAd = require('FBAudienceNetwork/FBInterstitialAd');`
3. Load the ad (taken as an example from the official docs)

   var ad = FBInterstitialAd.alloc(). initWithPlacementID('YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID'); 
   ad.delegate = yourDelegate;
   ad.loadAd();

Comment: Hello, for now I am implementing it for android and this is what I have done till now https://pastebin.com/cLxdg9BJ . I am following this link for reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-instream. I am getting "No fill" error I googled and found that my device should have Facebook app installed and I should logged into it with the id I added as tester. I followed this still getting same error.

Comment: getErrorMessage() prints "No fill"